# Running dnf update on Fedora returns conflicts for MongoDB

Tags: fedora, dnf, mongodb

I'd appreciate some advice resolving the following conflict with MongoDB install on my Fedora Workstation. I've added MongoDB as a custom repo and get the following output in the terminal when running `sudo dnf update`.

```
Fedora 35 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                         69 kB/s |  19 kB     00:00    
Fedora Modular 35 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                 46 kB/s |  21 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 35 - Free tainted                                                              23 kB/s | 3.6 kB     00:00    
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.12, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 3: package mongodb-org-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.12, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.12, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mongodb-org-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 4: problem with installed package mongodb-org-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-mongos = 4.4.4, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.10-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.10, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.11-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.11, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.12, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.5, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.6-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.7-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.8-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-4.4.9-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-tools = 4.4.9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both mongodb-org-mongos-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64 and mongodb-org-mongos-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install both mongodb-org-mongos-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64 and mongodb-org-mongos-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.10-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.10, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.11-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.11, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.12, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.5, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.6-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.6, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.7-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.8-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package mongodb-org-tools-4.4.9-1.el8.x86_64 requires mongodb-org-database-tools-extra = 4.4.9, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package mongodb-org-mongos-4.4.4-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.10-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.11-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.12-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.6-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.7-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.8-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides /usr/libexec/platform-python needed by mongodb-org-database-tools-extra-4.4.9-1.el8.x86_64
====================================================================================================================================
 Package                                          Architecture           Version                      Repository               Size
====================================================================================================================================
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 mongodb-org-mongos                               x86_64                 4.4.12-1.el8                 Mongodb                  17 M
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.10-1.el8                 Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.11-1.el8                 Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.12-1.el8                 Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.5-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.6-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.7-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.8-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org                                      x86_64                 4.4.9-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.10-1.el8                 Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.11-1.el8                 Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.12-1.el8                 Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.5-1.el8                  Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.6-1.el8                  Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.7-1.el8                  Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.8-1.el8                  Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-database-tools-extra                 x86_64                 4.4.9-1.el8                  Mongodb                  23 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.10-1.el8                 Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.11-1.el8                 Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.12-1.el8                 Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.5-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.6-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.7-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.8-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k
 mongodb-org-tools                                x86_64                 4.4.9-1.el8                  Mongodb                  11 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================
Skip  25 Packages
```

I've tried as the output suggest that running `sudo dnf update --best --allowerasing` would uninstall and reinstall MongoDB. However, it returns the same conflicts. I'd appreciate some advice or suggest work around. I am using the repo information published on this page, https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/database/mongodb/about.html.

Comment: It's a bit of work, and don't try unless you're familiar with building/installing packages, but you could [build/install from source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/building.md "MongoDB build instructions-->").  I did it on Fedora and it works fine, and you can use the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That repo appears to be for RHEL8 and likely doesn’t work with Fedora anymore.  I suggest removing all the packages you got from the third-party repo and use the ones in the Fedora repos.

```
dnf remove mongodb-org*
```

… should remove them all.

Comment: Ah crap :) I've run into this, installed the redhat 4.4 version of mongo a month or two ago, got these python errors trying to upgrade, now I've uninstalled the existing mongo packages and cannot reinstall anything.  According to a post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68617654/error-problem-nothing-provides-usr-libexec-platform-python-needed-by-mongodb the Mongo team do not support Fedora at all, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-58870. @jsbillings I cannot see any mongodb packages in the Fedora repos, what are you referring to please?

Comment: Follow up: Following the advice in the SERVER-58870 report, I was able to download the "Redhat / Centos 8.0" version of the mongo package and install on my Fedora 35 dev machine, so at least the server is running.  It's not managed by a repo any more, so won't upgrade automatically, and I don't have the shell and possibly other tools, but for my current needs (backend to Graylog) it's working.